# mi app solo funciona conectada al mismo wifi que el ordenador que ejecuta mi servidor

Tags: flutter, server, pgadmin

El servidor al que intento acceder lo tengo ejecutándose en mi ordenador de desarrollo, y la IP en la que escucha es privada por lo que, si la app está conectada a la misma red que el servidor, funciona, pero tan pronto como la app se ejecuta en otra red (la de telefonía) deja de funcionar, es decir, ya no me devuelve ninguna informacion almacenada en mi servidor.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar mi servidor a una IP Pública?

Comment: tienes una ip publica, puedes verla con cualquier herramienta tipo "what is my ip", pero tu router tiene un firewall asi que posiblemente no puedas conectarte. Además la ip seguro es dinamica asi que cambiará constantemente.  Necesitas contratar un servicio de hosting.

Comment: Debes acceder a tu router y mapear el/los puerto/s necesarios desde el router a tu IP privada para que externamente puedas acceder a ella mediante la IP pública de tu conexión telefónica. Entra en tu router y busca eso, mapear, servidores virtuales, forwarding, etc (ponen distintos nombres para lo mismo segun el fabricante), hasta que encuentres el lugar donde puedes hacer ese mapping. Suerte